# Ruby Complex number formatting Division

Tags: ruby, complex-numbers

```
puts 5 / Complex(1, 2)
```

Actual Output:

```
>>> 1/1-2/1i
```

Expected Output:

```
>>> 1 - 2i
```

Why does Ruby format this expression so that it includes rational numbers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is true, of course that

```
5/Complex(1, 2) #=> ((1/1)-(2/1)*i)
```

is the same as

```
(1-2i)
```

but in general, because of how complex division works<sup>1</sup>, the resulting coefficients of the real and imaginary parts of the complex number returned are not necessarily integers, but are rationals.

For example, suppose

```
c1 = Complex(1,2)
  #=> (1+2i)
c2 = Complex(2,3)
  #=> (2+3i)
```

and you wished to compute the quotient of these two numbers:

```
c1/c2
  #=> ((8/13)+(1/13)*i)
```

Of necessity, the result must be expressed with rational components.

Now consider the following operations.

```
c2 = Complex(3/4r, 5) #=> ((3/4)+5i)
c3 = Complex(2, 5.0)  #=> (2+5.0i)
1 + c1                #=> (2+2i)
1 - c1                #=> (0-2i)
2 * c1                #=> (2+4i)
c1/3                  #=> ((1/3)+(2/3)*i)
2.0 * c1              #=> (2.0+4.0i)
c1 + c2               #=> ((7/4)+7i)
c1 + c2               #=> ((7/4)+7i)
c1 * c1               #=> (-3+4i)
c1 * c2               #=> ((-37/4)+(13/2)*i)
c1 * c3               #=> (-8.0+9.0i)
c2 * c3               #=> (-23.5+13.75i)
```

You can see that the rules concerning the data type resulting from arithmetic operations involving combinations of integer, rational and floating-point numbers applies equally to the real and imaginary parts of complex numbers.

<sup>1 Complex division is explained [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ComplexDivision.html)</sup>